# How to place all month names in hashmap and replacing January as Jan and Febraury as Feb?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
HashMap hm = new HashMap();
        hm.put("January", "Jan");
        hm.put("Febraury", "Feb");
        hm.put("March", "Mar");
        hm.put("April", "Apr");
        hm.put("May", "May");
        hm.put("June", "Jun");
        hm.put("July", "Jul");
        hm.put("August", "Aug");
        hm.put("September", "Sep");
        hm.put("October", "Oct");
        hm.put("November", "Nov");
        hm.put("December", "Dec");
        for (int k = 1; k <= 12; k++) {
            if (Time.contains("January")) {

            }
        }
```

Where Time contains like September 25,2013 then expected output is Sep 25,2013 .how can i do like this,thanks in advance

Comment: what Time means ?? is it a class.. u can use SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Suppose Time=September 25,2013

Comment: Is the intention of your question that Time could be a much longer string?  I'm thinking of "Frederick March died on September 25, 2013; and his wife April died the next day".

Comment: why do u need a hashmap for it? u can use SimpleDateFormat to format the date string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            String time = "September 25,2013";
            HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hm.put("January", "Jan");
            hm.put("Febraury", "Feb");
            hm.put("March", "Mar");
            hm.put("April", "Apr");
            hm.put("May", "May");
            hm.put("June", "Jun");
            hm.put("July", "Jul");
            hm.put("August", "Aug");
            hm.put("September", "Sep");
            hm.put("October", "Oct");
            hm.put("November", "Nov");
            hm.put("December", "Dec");
            for (String key : hm.keySet()) {
                if (time.contains(key)) {
                    String newTime = time.replace(key, hm.get(key));
                    System.out.println(newTime);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use simpleDateFormat to convert the date to your desired pattern. This will convert date to your desired format and you will no need to keep the Janurary as Jan in hashmap.

```
String date = "September 25,2013";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy");
System.out.println(formatter.format(new Date(date)));
```

Output:

```
Sep 25,2013
```

Answer (score 0):

If `time` is:

```
String time = "September 25, 2013";
```

then you can use the `String#replace()` method:

```
time = time.replace("September", (String) hm.get("September"));
```

**Note:** To avoid the explicit *cast* to `String`, you can declare your `HashMap` like:

```
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
```

And if you want to iterate through the `EntrySet`s of the `HashMap`, so you replace every ocurrence of the keys, use a `for` loop:

```
for (Entry<String, String> es : hm.entrySet()) {
    time = time.replace(es.getKey(), es.getValue());
}
```

Comment: How can i integrate with my current code,could you guide me please?

Comment: I would iterate through the entry set, not the key set, so that you don't have to access the map a second time, to get the value.

Comment: @DavidWallace you are right, edited. user3297398 What's your current code?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
    HashMap hm = new HashMap();
    hm.put("January", "Jan");
    hm.put("Febraury", "Feb");
    hm.put("March", "Mar");
    hm.put("April", "Apr");
    hm.put("May", "May");
    hm.put("June", "Jun");
    hm.put("July", "Jul");
    hm.put("August", "Aug");
    hm.put("September", "Sep");
    hm.put("October", "Oct");
    hm.put("November", "Nov");
    hm.put("December", "Dec");

    String time = "September 25,2013";
    Set hset = hm.keySet();
   Iterator ite =  hset.iterator();    

    while(ite.hasNext()) {          
        String monthName = (String)ite.next();
         if (time.contains(monthName)) {            
             time = time.replace(monthName, (String)hm.get(monthName));
             break;

         }
    }
    System.out.println(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

## java.time In Java 8

If your question is really about how to format a date (as stated in your last line), and not really about HashMap, here's how to do it with the new [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8). The java.time package is inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Notice that you can easily localize to various languages and their various customs such as different number of characters in the abbreviation of the month name. I'm showing formatting for France as output, but you can switch to `Locale.US`.

```
String input = "September 25, 2013";
DateTimeFormatter formatterInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMMM d, yyyy" ).withLocale( java.util.Locale.ENGLISH );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input, formatterInput );

//DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM" ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( Locale.FRANCE );

String output = formatterOutput.format( localDate );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "localDate: " + localDate );
System.out.println( "output: " + output ););
```

When run…

```
localDate: 2013-09-25
output: 25 sept. 2013
```